# Turn a 2 second order array into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set as such of 2 order array, with arbitrary length. as shown below

```
 [['15,39' '17,43']
  ['23,40' '18,44']
  ['28,41' '18,45']
  ['28,42' '27,46']
  ['34,43' '26,47']
  .
  .
  .
                   ]
```

I want to turn it into a panda dataframe as columns and rows, shown below

```
15 39 17 43
23 40 18 44
28 41 18 45
28 42 27 46
34 43 26 47
.
.
.
```

anyone has idea how to achieve it without saving the data out to files during process?

Answer (score 0):

My strategy is defining a function first to deal with the comma and quotes. Keeping in mind that your data is already a 2 dimensional numpy array I define the following function:

```
def str_to_flt(lst):
    tmp = np.array([[float(i.split(",")[0]),float(i.split(",")[1])] for i in lst])
    return tmp

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((str_to_flt(data[:,0]), str_to_flt(data[:,1])), axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
from io import StringIO

s="""[['15,39' '17,43']
['23,40' '18,44']
['28,41' '18,45']
['28,42' '27,46']
['34,43' '26,47']]"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),header=None)
```

You can do:

```
d={"\[\['":"","'\]\]":"","'\]\]'":"","'\]":"","\['":"","' '":','}
df=df.replace(d,regex=True)
df[[1.2,1.5]]=df.pop(1).str.extract(r"(\d+),(\d+)")
df=df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

output of `df`:

```
    0.0     1.2     1.5     2.0
0   15      39      17      43
1   23      40      18      44
2   28      41      18      45
3   28      42      27      46
4   34      43      26      47
```

Ofcourse you can rename the name of columns according to your need by using `columns` attribute or `rename()` method and typecast data by using `astype()` method according to your need