# 2 order array transform to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set as such of 2 order array, with arbitrary length. as shown below

```
[['15,39' '17,43']
['23,40' '18,44']
['28,41' '18,45']
['28,42' '27,46']
['34,43' '26,47']
.
.
.
                 ]
```

I want to turn it into a panda dataframe as columns and rows, shown below

```
15 39 17 43
23 40 18 44
28 41 18 45
28 42 27 46
34 43 26 47
.
.
.
```

anyone has idea how to achieve it without saving the data out to files during process?

Comment: show what you have tried?? code!! also in this ```['15,39' '17,43']``` are you missing a comma?

Comment: It's the same question that you asked 36 minutes ago with your second account https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517852/turn-a-2-second-order-array-into-pandas-dataframe

Comment: no i am not missing any comma, the data is exactly as I wrote

Comment: This is the content of a file, this a string? Where the data come from?

Answer (score 0):

Importing pandas would be the first step

```
import pandas as pd
```

Now, we have to save the 2d array into the list

As the output dataframe contains only integer datatype we have to remove all the quotes and add comas where needed. For example

```
lst = [[ 15, 39, 17, 43],[ 23, 40, 18, 44],[ 28, 41, 18, 45],[ 28, 42, 27, 46],[ 34, 43, 26, 47 ]]
```

now using the pandas library we convert the list into a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = [ 'cl1 ', 'cl2', 'cl3', 'cl4' ] )
```

Now the only thing remaining is to print and check the output dataframe.

```
print(df)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list you have to a pandas dataframe like this,

```
import pandas as pd

data = \
[['15,39', '17,43'],
['23,40', '18,44'],
['28,41', '18,45'],
['28,42', '27,46'],
['34,43', '26,47']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, to add columns like you want,

```
df.pop(0).str.split(",", expand=True).rename(columns={0: "col_0", 1: "col_1"}) \
    .join(df.pop(1).str.split(",", expand=True).rename(columns={0: "col_2", 1: "col_3"}))

   col_0 col_1 col_2 col_3
0   15  39  17  43
1   23  40  18  44
2   28  41  18  45
3   28  42  27  46
4   34  43  26  47
```